# How to use Win32_UserAccount rename method?

Tags: powershell

I am able to use `Get-CimInstance Win32_UserAccount` to list users on remote computers. Once I get the users, I would like to rename the administrator account. Below is the code but it does not work. Any tips on making this work?

```
$hostname = "SERVER1"
$newname  = "Server_Admin"
$administrator = Get-CimInstance Win32_UserAccount -ComputerName $hostname |
                 where SID -like 'S-1-5-*-500' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$oldname = $administrator.Name

$oldname.Rename($newname)
```

Above command failed with the error

> Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'rename'.

Using `Set-CimInstance`

```
Set-CimInstance -InputObject $administrator -Property @{name=$newname} -PassThru
```

gives an error

> Could not modify readonly property 'name' of object 'Win32_UserAccount"

PowerShell version used is 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

## Using PowerShell version 5.1

### Using Invoke-CIMMethod I was able to rename the account.

```
$serverlist = Get-Content C:\Temp\servers.txt
$newname = "Server_Admin"

foreach ($hostname in $serverlist)
{
#Check if server is online.
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $hostname -Count 1 -Delay 2 -BufferSize 1452 -Quiet)
    {
#Get the Administrator user from the remote computer
        $administrator = get-ciminstance win32_useraccount -ComputerName $hostname  | Where-Object SID -Like 'S-1-5-*-500' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
#Display retrieved account
        write-host $administrator
#Rename the administrator account
        Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $administrator -ComputerName $hostname -MethodName "Rename" -Arguments @{name = $newname }
#Get and display account details for the renamed account
        get-ciminstance win32_useraccount -ComputerName $hostname | Where-Object SID -Like 'S-1-5-*-500' | Select-Object Name,FullName,Status,Disabled,Lockout,Domain,LocalAccount,SID,SIDType,AccountType | sort Status | format-table -groupby Status 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in that use case, the CIM cmdlet DOES NOT return a live object. *there is NO `.Rename()` method attached to that object*.

however, the WMI cmdlet *DOES* return a live object with a `.Rename()` method. so ... use `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount` instead of `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserAccount`. [*grin*]

Comment: See the answer below, with CIM you'll need to use invoke-cimmethod, there is also a similar cmdlet for WMI invoke-wmimethod

Comment: @JeffPatton - sure! that is what i thot i was saying. should i add more detail to my rather short Answer?

Comment: perhaps the OP appears to be talking about the CIM cmdlets as opposed to WMI. A more rounded WMI answer could be beneficial, but it feels like things are moving away from WMI in favor of CIM.

Comment: @JeffPatton - i will leave the Answer as is, then. thank you for your input! [*grin*]